# Dyanmic Droppable Div Not Work in First Time jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

> **Note:**

1. I have tried other question asked in stackoverflow related to
   **Dyanmic Droppable Div**  i'm unable to do so.
2. **I can Not Drop Textbox In Add New Dynamic Div For first time.**

**Step:**

1. First Create new div using drag and drop DIV control.
2. Then Click on `'Add New Div'` from right corner. This will create new div in   panel.
3. **I'm unable to drop a textbox in newly created DIV for first time.**
4. After dropping `textbox` in panel, i am able to drop textbox on newly created DIV.

**I want to**

1. drop textbox on newly created DIV at first attempt.

Here is my [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/3y08gbdy/) Code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add that at the end of your **AddnewDiv** function:

```
$(".claspaneldiv").sortable({
    placeholder: 'cs_block-placeholder'
});
```

Comment: Thanks. @Alanfabeta  it's  working..